# MySQL: Is UNION what I am looking for? (break row up into multiple row return)

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id
first
last
institution
address
space1_1_value
space1_2_value
space2_1_value
space2_2_value
space3_1_value
space3_2_value
agreement
```

> ** trimmed down field count for example sake. **

In the end, I want to export my query to a spreadsheet, but I cant seem to get a nice working query. (hence the post)

While one record/row in the table will have value(s) for id, first, last, institution, address, space1_1_value, space1_2_value and agreement fields/cols...

it may or may not have values for the cols:

space2_1_value
space2_2_value
and
space3_1_value
space3_2_value

I'm not sure to explain it.. but more or less,.. I want to break up each record/row in the table to 1-3 'rows' (for lack of a better explanation)

So for EACH ROW/RECORD in the table..

I want to return the following:

> id | first | last | institution | address | space1_1_value |
>   space1_2_value | agreement

if there are value in space2_1_value then:

> id | first | last | institution | address | space2_1_value |
>   space2_2_value | agreement

if there are value in space3_1_value then:

> id | first | last | institution | address |  space3_1_value |
>   space3_2_value | agreement

To summarize.. EACH record has all the initial cols listed above. I am trying to 'break up' the return for each row by 'spaceX_X_value' groups.. if not empty.

Reading here:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

it says to use UNION for vertically appending results..

but I havent been able to get anything worth while working.

failed attempt (seems to bloated)... I feel like I can specifically select the 'static/commons' fields in each desired row/result, and UNION/SELECT the different spaceX_Xvalue groups.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    (SELECT first, last, space2_value FROM report WHERE space2_value <> '')
    UNION
    (SELECT first, last, space3_value FROM report WHERE space3_value <> '')
) AS results
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

From the comments below...this is a working example:  (just feels a bit redundant typing out the same cols names like first, last..etc for each select)

```
SELECT first, last, space1_value as space_value FROM report
UNION
SELECT first, last, space2_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space2_value <> ''
UNION
SELECT first, last, space3_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space3_value <> ''
ORDER BY first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT first, last, space2_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space2_value <> ''
        UNION
SELECT first, last, space3_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space3_value <> ''
```

Column names must be equal in every query for UINION

Comment: Why do you need the wrapping SELECT *? You should be well OK only with SELECT UNION SELECT UNION SELECT.

Comment: ahh..ok.  So I will have to list all fields out in each SELECT and not just the 'space' group specific fields..

I updated my answer to what gives me all cols now (as well as ordered by name)

Accepted answer for the tip.

Comment: Nice :) Mark answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using UNION ALL if you don't want duplicate rows to be automatically removed.

From MySQL documentation :

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`unpivot`** to make columns into rows:

**Data:** I created a table called `yourtable` and populated with some data:

```
id          first      last       institution address              space1_1_value space1_2_value space2_1_value space2_2_value space3_1_value space3_2_value agreement
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------------
1           oliver     koo        mac         123 street           1              1              2              3              3              5              agree
2           mr.derp    herp       carl        sesame street        7              7              NULL           1              4              9              disagree
```

**Query:** then I executed this query including tow *`unpivot` relational operators*:

```
SELECT id,first, last, institution, address, spacex_1_value , spacex_2_value
from yourtable

unpivot
(spacex_1_value for x1 in 
 (space1_1_value, space2_1_value,space3_1_value)
) unpvt1

unpivot
(
spacex_2_value for x2 in 
 (space1_2_value, space2_2_value,space3_2_value)
) unpvt2

WHERE SUBSTRING(x1,6,1) =  SUBSTRING(x2,6,1)
```

**Result:**

```
id          first      last       institution address              spacex_1_value spacex_2_value
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------------- -------------- --------------
1           oliver     koo        mac         123 street           1              1
1           oliver     koo        mac         123 street           2              3
1           oliver     koo        mac         123 street           3              5
2           mr.derp    herp       carl        sesame street        7              7
2           mr.derp    herp       carl        sesame street        4              9
```

note: the where clause is crucial on joining the x1 (not selected) and x2 (not selected) columns. Without it, we haven't told SQL Server how the second set of unpivoted data matches the first. SQL would do a cross join. So the where clause is necessary to filter out unwanted rows.

hope this helps

Comment: HI-

Thank you for turning me on to UNPIVOT.  I"ll look more into it.  However, this does NOT produce the results desired posted in the original question/post.  Space_1_value col should only be 1 one returned row

Space_2_value should never be in same returned results/row as Space_1_value....etc..  they should be their own ROWS  (not columns in the same row)